# Getting "Could not open data connection to port xxxx" when uploading file to FTP from Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-upload, ftp

I am trying to upload a text file to FTP server using a batch file. It logins successfully and shows

> Port command sent successfully

but after that shows

> Could not open data connection to port xxxx
>   Connection timed out

This is the batch script:

```
@echo off

for %%A in (*.csv) do set latest=%%A 
echo Latest file is %latest%  

echo MYUSERNAME> upload.txt 
echo MYPASSWORD>> upload.txt 
echo asc>>upload.txt 
echo put %latest% s.txt>> upload.txt 
echo quit >> upload.txt  

ftp -s:upload.txt server58.hostinger.in
```

Answer (score 8):

This looks like a typical problem with an FTP active mode. The server cannot connect back to your machine to establish a data transfer connection.

That typically happens as nowadays most client machines are behind a firewall or NAT or both, what prevents the FTP active mode from working. To make the active mode working you need to open your firewall (not recommended) and/or configure NAT routing rules.

See my article on [FTP modes and configuring network for an active mode](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

---

Or you use a passive FTP mode. The Windows `ftp.exe` client does not support the passive mode though, what makes it pretty useless nowadays.

So you need to use another command-line FTP client. A majority of FTP clients do support the passive mode.

For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) your batch file would be like:

```
@echo off

for %%A in (*.csv) do set latest=%%A 
echo Latest file is %latest%

winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@server58.hostinger.in/" ^
    "put -transfer=ascii %latest% s.txt" ^
    "exit"
```

Note that WinSCP defaults to the passive mode.

For details see WinSCP guides for:

- [Automating file transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation)
- [Converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp)

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*